# Turn caching off in debug mode in Django

Tags: django

I am using memcached view caching for my production servers on some very computationally & DB intense views, like so:

```
urlpatterns = ('',
    (r'^foo/(\d{1,2})/$', cache_page(60 * 15)(my_view)),
)
```

Is there a way to turn caching off when DEBUG==True in Settings.py so that I don't have to worry about obselete view outputs being cached and can use my IDE's debugger?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set up caches conditionally in your `settings.py`, like this:

```
if not DEBUG:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
            'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        }
    }
else:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cool. I was aware of using conditionals in my settings files, but didn't know about the DummyCache.  I also tried conditionally setting CACHES to an empty dictionary (before I saw your answer) and that seemed to be working out ok, although using DummyCache looks like the right way to do it.